# Calculating the number of dates in specific year, between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range, date-difference

I'm trying to figure this out, but it's driving me insane! How do I calculate in SQL the number of days  that are in a specific year between two dates? For example: we have the range date [12/30/2016-01/05/2017]. If I need to find how many days are in 2017 between this range of dates, it would be 5 days. How is that done in SQL?

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the tips. I’m new here so I’ll try to do better.

Comment: Sounds good. Although your question has been answered, it's still good to add the dbms tag now. That way the next person with the same problem has an easier time finding this thread :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify your dbms, but in general terms:

- Get the 1st day of the @EndDate year i.e. *January 1, 2017*
- Then calculate the days difference between @FirstOfYear and @EndDate

For example in MySQL, you could use [MAKEDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate) to get the first of the year. Then [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to calculate the number of days

```
SET @StartDate = '2016-12-30';
SET @EndDate = '2017-01-05';  

SELECT DateDiff(@endDate, MAKEDATE(Year(@endDate),1)) + 1 AS DaysInEndDateYear
```

**Result:**

> ```
> | DaysDiffValue|
> | ----------------: |
> |                 5 |
> ```

If you also need to handle ranges where both @StartDate and @EndDate are in the same year:

```
SET @StartDate = '2017-01-05';
SET @EndDate = '2017-03-14';  

SELECT CASE WHEN Year(@StartDate) = Year(@EndDate) THEN DateDiff(@EndDate, @StartDate) + 1
            ELSE DateDiff(@endDate, MAKEDATE(Year(@endDate),1)) + 1
       END AS DaysInEndDateYear
```

**Results:**

> ```
> | DaysInEndDateYear |
> | ----------------: |
> |                69 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dee87b0839ae0035d6ab9c5f21f43f54)*

Comment: Thank you very much! I did something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but if your using PostgreSQL you can use a [date range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) to calculate this.

Your question is essentially the length of the intersection between a given date range and the range for "2017":

```
select daterange('2016-12-30', '2017-01-05', '[]') * daterange('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01')
```

The upper bound is excluded by default in a daterange, that's why the range for "2017" specifies 2018-01-01 as the (excluded) upper bound. The `*` operator calculates the [intersection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) between those two ranges. I assumed that you want to *include* 2017-01-05 in the rage to be tested, that's why it's created with an inclusive upper bound (`'[]'`).

The length is then calculated by subtracting the lower bound from the upper bound:

```
select upper(result) - lower(result) as days
from ( 
   select daterange('2016-12-30', '2017-01-05', '[]') * daterange('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01')
) t(result)
```

Comment: This is most helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Although I haven't used PostgreSQL, posts like this make me want to start! It has some slick functions not found in the db's I've used.

Answer (score 0):

The practical answer to this is "it depends on the database vendor" as even simple date calculations vary substantially e.g.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-01-05','2016-12-30');
```

**TSQL (MS SQL Server)**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( day,'2016-12-30', '2017-01-05')
```

**Postgres**

```
SELECT '2017-01-05'::DATE - '2016-12-30'::DATE
```

**Firebird**
and in Postgres there are alternatives to that also.

**Oracle**

```
SELECT (date '2017-01-05') - (date '2016-12-30') from dual
```

and in Oracle there are alternatives to that also.

**Firebird**

```
select datediff(day,cast('2016-12-30' as date),cast('2017-01-05' as date)) from rdb$database
```

Your request involves a need to manipulate dates so it is necessary to know which database.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the result NotonGoogle is looking for. The question is phrased as "*how many days are in 2017*" so I think it's not as simple as subtracting the start from the end.

Comment: It does not fully answer it you are correct, but I'm not providing more without identification of the target dB.

Comment: I guess my nickname is NotonGoogle now! . Thank you for all your information. All these are helping me learn more. Much appreciated!

Comment: In future PLEASE use a tag that is the database you need the answer for - not "sql"